# docker-compose translate to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, openshift

i have a docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest

  assets:
    image: gnaudio/jabra-xpress-assets:v4.0.7020

  frontend:
    image: gnaudio/jabra-xpress-frontend:v4.0.7314
    environment:
    - "ENDPOINT=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:85"
    ports:
    - "80:80"

  backend:
    image: gnaudio/jabra-xpress-api:v4.0.7313
    environment:
    - "ConnectionStrings:XpressDatabaseSqlServer=¤CONNSTRING¤"
    - "ConnectionStrings:MongoDb=mongodb://mongodb/raw"
    - "DefaultAnalyticsEndpoint=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:88/api/v1/Analytics"
    - "JDODownload=http://assets/"
    - "NetworkEndpoint=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:85/api/Xpress/Network/"
    - "SDK:fwURL_base=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:82"
    - "SDK:fsURL_base=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:82"
    ports:
    - "85:80"
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
    - assets
    - sdkbackend

  sdkbackend:
    image: gnaudio/jabra-xpress-sdkbackend:latest
    environment:
    - "Storage:SDKCopyUrl=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:82"
    ports:
    - "82:80"

  analytics:
    image: gnaudio/jabra-xpress-analytics:v4.0.7312
    environment:
    - "ConnectionStrings:MongodbServer=mongodb://mongodb/raw"
    ports:
    - "88:80"
    depends_on:
    - mongodb

  analytics-cron:
    image: gnaudio/jabra-xpress-analytics-cron:v4.0.7313
    environment:
    - "MONGODBCONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb://mongodb/raw"
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
```

I know I can translate this with kompose up to kubernetes. But what is with the Parts "DefaultAnalyticsEndpoint=http://¤HOST-NAME¤:88/api/v1/Analytics"?

According to the producer of Jabra, you should do that:

Replace ¤CONNSTRING¤ with the SQL connection string
Replace ¤HOST-NAME¤ with the server host-name.

What hostname I have to do put in there? I mean I have 6 different Services and Pods. How can they communicate with each other?

Answer (score 2):

As with Docker(-Compose), Kubernetes includes a DNS service that permits you to reference e.g. Services (Capitalized means the Kubernetes type).

IIRC, Kompose generates Services and Deployments for Docker-Compose services. You will generally refer to Kubernetes services through the Service type and you should have Services for e.g. `frontend`, `backend` etc.

So, in answer to your question, depending on which Service you wish to reference, you will replace `${HOST_NAME}` with one of the Service names. It would appear that `DefaultAnalyticsEndpoint` references the Docker-Compose service `analytics`. This should be mapped to a Kubernetes Service called `analytics` too. IIUC, in both case (Docker-Compose and Kubernetes), The `HOST-NAME` in `DefaultAnalyticsEndpoint` would be `analytics`.

If you reference a Service from within the same Namespace, you need only use the Service name e.g. `backend`. If you refer to a Service from another Namespace, you will need to include the Namespace specifier, e.g. `backend.${NAMESPACE}.cluster.local`

See:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services

Comment: THX. I have created a route that refers to the frontend service. The problem is, when the frontend service tries to reach the backend service, I got the following error in Browser

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://backend:85/api/UserManagement/NewCompany' from origin 'http://XXXX.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polyfills.1430e9e37c917675a879.js:1 POST http://backend:85/api/UserManagement/NewCompany net::ERR_FAILED
Any idea what that can be?

Comment: This is a different question. The error message explains the issue. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) explanation of CORS. It's curious that this issue does not arise on Docker-Compose because that request (across services) should be across different origins too.